# Fire Event to Open CartoDB/Leaflet Marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've got a pretty specific question that I'm not really expecting a direct answer to, but any guidance will be helpful.

Simple and plain, I want to programmatically fire a click event on a marker positioned on a Leaflet map, powered by CartoDB.  I have a single layer on the map that contains markers, and each marker has click events associated with them.  So, essentially, I just need to find the marker and fire the click event on it.

For context, Mapbox actually does exactly this, but unfortunately I can not use Mapbox for this particular implementation:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/open-popup-externally/

I'm open to suggestions, but preferably, I'd like to do something similar to the code in the link above -- interrogate either Leaflet or CartoDB via javascript to find and access the marker via custom properties/lat-lng/??.  I figure it would be simple enough to go from there.

Another way could be to hook an event when the markers are created, store them in a hash, then access that storage when I need to do my manual click.  However, I don't know of any such event that exists, and I can't locate documentation that lists supported events.

Since I'm not creating the markers myself, and can not (for reasons), storing them as I add them to the map is not an option here.

I assume since Mapbox is doing it, there must be some hook, but I can't find any valuable documentation to point me in the right direction.

Any suggestions or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who stumbles upon this, I've got a workable solution for my particular case.  This call will do it for you:

```
layer.trigger 'featureClick', event, latlng, pos, data, layer_count
```

Essentially, you'll want to grab the layer in question and trigger the click, passing the appropriate data:

- event: this can be null, since there is no event
- latlng: the lat/long position
- data: an object like `{ cartodb_id: 123 }`. The cartodb_id is required.
- layer_count: the index of your layer (probably 0)

To grab the latlng and the cartodb_id here, you'll probably need to do what I did -- query for it:

```
function openMarker(layer, my_object_id) {
  vars = { database_id: my_object_id };
  opts = { format: 'geojson' };
  query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_object_id = {{ my_object_id }}"
  sql = new cartodb.SQL({user: my_user_id});
  sql.execute(query, vars, opts).done(function(data) {
    if (data.features != undefined && data.features.length == 1)
      row = data.features[0];
      latlng = [ row.geometry.coordinates[1], row.geometry.coordinates[0] ];
      layer.trigger('featureClick', null, latlng, null, { cartodb_id: row.properties.cartodb_id }, 0);
  });
}
```

Then, you can just call open_marker, passing the layer you wish to open the marker on and your object identifier.  As long as that's in your cartodb database, you can grab it.  Of course, the query can be adjusted to suit your means.

For my particular implementation, I had to use a setTimeout call to get the flow of control right, as I do my calls on page load.  But if you're calling after the page has loaded, should be no problem.

So, simple enough way to open a marker given a local identifier.  Hope this helps someone else!

Kudos for the inspiration for this solution go to:
https://gist.github.com/javisantana/7b817fda1e7511c451c7#file-index-html-L39

Comment: When I query the SQL API from CartoDB, the row.coordinates comes back in GeoJSON format, which gives me an array of double values [ long, lat ].  For the call to layer.trigger, I need [ lat, long ], so I invert the array.  Note, my database has Points, so it uses that format for row.coordinates; the GeoJSON returned could vary depending on your particular database implementation.  For details, see http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html#response-formats and http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geojson-objects . Hope that helps.